# Timeout sending email with Cakemail

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send an email using CakeMail.
I'm using Wamp Server, ok?

My email.php is this:

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'from' => array('support@xxx.com' => 'xxx'),
    'port' => 465,
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'username' => 'igorpoxxx@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'xxx',

);
```

In My controller:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
$Email->to('igor.ces@sotreq.com');
$Email->subject('About');
$Email->send('My message');
```

And I get Timeout!!!

**Fatal Error
Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

File: C:\wamp\www\societario\lib\Cake\Network\CakeSocket.php

Line: 190**

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I tested the application in another network and this work fine. Although the first network having Internet for some reason it's don't work.
Was some kind of network problem.
Thanks